# positioning object inside container with offSet

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, offset

Hey guys I’m trying to make simple point & click game, in background will be some nice landscape which will be moved by arrows on the left and right (same like slider works), I want object to move only within the lower div (#boxMap), I tried to build contructor to main object but together with friend who helps me, we wrote it in way below. The problem is that this object still doesn’t move how it should be, idea is that when game starts, and when I click right arrow, object appears on the left, if I click left arrow object appears on the left side of the div. When I click the mouse, object should moves to position I clicked. I’m kinda desperate as I have ideas how to make It work later but I totally cannot manage this positioning and movement of the object.
I found some nice yt tutorial about moving objects and tried to set statements to move only within the div without getting outside the edge, unfortunately now it moves only on the bottom edge of div.

So I created new object with class .hero inside the boxMap, and set it’s starting position with css properties, then with function getClickPosition I try to manage it’s movement, I try also set that if object is clicked outside the frame of div, it set it’s position on particular value. Unfortunately now it moves only through the bottom edge, right side it doesn’t exceed the edge, left side it does.

Hope I was able to more or less explain what I try to achieve and what I have already done.
Any idea how to set position and some simple movement in much simpler way?
I would be grateful for any tips

```
HTML

<body>
<div id="emptySpace">
    <span class="left"></span>
    <span class="right"></span>
</div>

<div id="boxMap">

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

CSS

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  #emptySpace {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70vh;
    background-color: azure;
    position: relative;
    .left {
      position: absolute;
      left: 10px;
      top: 40vh;
      border-top: 40px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
      border-right:40px solid blue;
      //display: none;
    }
    .right {
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      top: 40vh;
      border-top: 40px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
      border-left: 40px solid green;
      //display: none;
    }
  }
  #boxMap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30vh;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #d8fffa;
    position: relative;
    .hero {
      position: absolute;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: blue;
      transform: translate3d(0px, -45px, 0);
      transition: 2s linear;
    }
  }
}



Javascript

function Game() {
    this.hero = new Hero();
   this.counter = 0;
    var self = this;
    this.boxMap = document.querySelector("#boxMap");
    // Placing hero on the map
    this.showHero = function () {
        var heroElement = document.createElement('div');
        heroElement.classList.add('hero');
        console.log(self, self.boxMap);
        self.boxMap.appendChild(heroElement);
        $(heroElement).css({top: 130, left: 30})
    }

}


var game = new Game();
game.showHero();


var heroMovement = document.querySelector(".hero");
var boxMap = document.querySelector("#boxMap");

boxMap.addEventListener("click", getClickPosition, false);


// Set position on hero and set movement
function getClickPosition(e) {
   var xPosition = e.clientX;
    var maxWidth = 1350;
    var minWidth = -20;
    if (xPosition < minWidth) {
        xPosition = minWidth;
    } else if (xPosition > maxWidth) {
        xPosition = maxWidth
    } else {
        var xPosition = e.clientX - (heroMovement.offsetWidth + 3);
    }

    var yPosition = e.clientY;
    var maxHeight = 60;
    var minHeight = -130;
    if (yPosition < minHeight) {
        yPosition = minHeight;
    } else if (yPosition > maxHeight) {
        yPosition = maxHeight
    } else {
        var yPosition = e.clientY - (heroMovement.offsetHeight + 558);
    }

   console.log(xPosition, yPosition);
    var translate3dValue = "translate3d(" + xPosition + "px" + "," + yPosition + "px, 0)";
    console.log(translate3dValue);
    heroMovement.style.transform = translate3dValue;
}
```